# Laravel Carbon check if time is within the same minute

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-5

I have datetime from a database and a datetime coming from an `input='time'` field.

I have one datetime without seconds (so it defaults to 00) and one with the seconds. I need to check if the two variables are in the same minute.

Example:  for True

```
Carbon {#349 ▼
  +"date": "2017-11-06 14:47:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "America/Chicago"
}
Carbon {#362 ▼
  +"date": "2017-11-06 14:47:44.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "America/Chicago"
}
```

Example: for False

```
Carbon {#349 ▼
  +"date": "2017-11-06 14:48:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "America/Chicago"
}
Carbon {#362 ▼
  +"date": "2017-11-06 14:47:44.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "America/Chicago"
}
```

I have this going now but it will show within the 60 seconds mark. I'm having a hard time displaying if it's within the same minute.

```
$InsertTime = 2017-11-06 14:47
$DbTime = 2017-11-06 14:47:44


public function WithinMinCheck($InsertTime, $DbTime) {
   $WithinMin = "true";
   $InsertTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $InsertTime);
   $DbTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $DbTime);
   $difference = $InsertTime->diffInSeconds($DbTime);
   if ($difference >= 60) {
    $WithinMin = "false";
   } else {
    $WithinMin = "true";
   }

   return $WithinMin;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cant you just set the second field of the second timevariable to 0 and compare the values?

```
$newTime = $DbTime->copy()->second(00);
if($InsertTime->ne($newTime)) {
    $WithinMin = "false";
}
return $WithinMin;  //since $withinMin is set to true initially, it would only be false if Insertime is not equal
```

Keep in mind, that the above solution will only work if the minute value is the same. If the second time has a different minute value, no matter even if it is within 60 seconds of the first, it will return false.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just compare dates as strings? It's quite simple.

```
$InsertTime = '2017-11-06 14:47';
$DbTime = '2017-11-06 14:47:44';

public function WithinMinCheck($InsertTime, $DbTime) {
   return (strpos($DbTime, $InsertTime) === 0);
}
```